# Mosaic Gallery to show images in Mosaic Style in android for lower sdk's?

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-2.2-froyo, mosaic

I am working for Mosaic style Gallery preview. In my last thread [Mosaic Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716325/show-images-from-gallery-in-mosaic-style-in-android?noredirect=1#comment25866039_17716325) I got to know how to implement it in Android using **QuiltView code** but getting problem in lower sdk's.

My code works only for the 4.0 and above O.S. and not for the lower sdks. Getting problem in the **GridLayout** which is in 4.0 and above O.S.

Please suggest me to solve the problem. I have to implement the Mosaic style in 2.2 and above O.S.
[image]

You can see my code which I am using in my last [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716325/show-images-from-gallery-in-mosaic-style-in-android/17743071#17743071). Grid layout which we have in 4.0 and not in lower O.S is creating problems for me.

Comment: Android is open-source, can you possible take code of ´QuiltView´ and copy it into your project under another namespace?

Comment: GridLayout is not there in below Android 4.0 O.S

Comment: So take its code too ?

Comment: What if there are 10 000 images in your gallery? ;)